# File validation when the file field isn't required

Tags: hooks, files

I have a Drupal 7 custom form where the image or file field is not required. When the form is submitted and no file/image has been uploaded, I get the following errors.

> Notice: Undefined index: storage in jobform_my_form_submit() (line 136 of /var/www/html/drupaltst/sites/all/modules/jobpackage/jobform.module).
> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in  jobform_my_form_submit() (line 141 of var/www/html/drupaltst/sites/all/modules/jobpackage/jobform.module).
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$uri in file_save() (line 601 of /var/www/html/drupaltst/includes/file.inc).

Any help is appreciated!

```php
function jobform_permission() {
  return array(
    'add jobs module' => array(
       'title' => t('Administer permission for your module'),
       'description' => t('Some description that would appear on the permission page..'),
    ),
  );
}

function jobform_menu() {
  $items = array();
  //$items['jobform/form'] = array(
  $items['jobform'] = array(
    'title' => t('Job Form Details'),
    'page callback' => 'jobform_form',
    'page arguments' => array('jobform_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('add jobs module'),
    'description' => t('My form'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
    
function jobform_form() {
  return drupal_get_form('jobform_my_form');
}
 
function jobform_my_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Title'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#maxlength' => 100,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="titletle"><img src="/drupaltst/sites/default/files/images/title_icon.png" height="50" width="45">', 
     '#suffix' => '</img></div>',
     '#attributes' => array(
       'placeholder' => t('Enter a Short Title'),
     ), 
   );    
   $form['descr'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textarea',
     '#title' => t('Description'),
     '#required' => TRUE,
     '#size' => 150,
     '#maxlength' => 5000,
     '#prefix' => '<div class="titledescr"><img src="/drupaltst/sites/default/files/images/descr_req_icon.png" height="50" width="45">', 
     '#suffix' => '</img></div>',
     '#attributes' => array(
       'placeholder' => t('Enter some specific details about the service you provide!'),
     ), 
   );       
   $form['location'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => t('Enter Your Location'),
     '#required' => TRUE,
     '#size' => 75,
     '#prefix' => '<div class="titleloc"><img src="/drupaltst/sites/default/files/images/loc_icon.png" height="50" width="41">', 
     '#suffix' => '</img></div>',
     '#attributes' => array(
      'placeholder' => t('Where Can the Work Be Completed? (i.e. Online, City, State, Zip)'),
     ),    
   );
        
   //Image Field
   $form['image'] = array(
     '#type' => 'file',
     '#title' => t('Upload a Photo'),
     '#description' => t('Allowed extensions: gif png jpg jpeg'),
     '#prefix' => '<br><div class="titlefile"><img src="/drupaltst/sites/default/files/images/upload_image_icon.png" height="50" width="41">', 
     '#suffix' => '</img></div>',
   );
   $form['submit'] = array(
     '#type' => 'submit',
     '#value' => 'Submit',
     '#prefix' => '<br><div class="titlesubmit">', 
     '#suffix' => '</div>',
   );
      
   return $form;
 }

 function jobform_my_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
   $file = file_save_upload('image', array(
     // Validates file is really an image.
     'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
     // Validate extensions.
     'file_validate_extensions' => array('png gif jpg jpeg'),
   ));
   // If the file passed validation:
   if ($file) {
     // Move the file into the Drupal file system.
     if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://images/')) {
       // Save the file for use in the submit handler.
       //$form_state['image'] = $file;
       $form_state['storage']['image'] = $file;
     }
     else {
       form_set_error('image', t("Failed to write the uploaded file to the site's file folder."));
     }
   } 
   else {
     form_set_error('image', t('No file was uploaded.'));
     //$file = file_move($file, 'public://images/title_icon.png');
   }
 }
   
 function jobform_my_form_submit($form, $form_state) {    
   $file = $form_state['storage']['image'];
   // We are done with the file, remove it from storage.
   //unset($form_state['image']);
   unset($form_state['storage']['image']);
   // Make the storage of the file permanent.
   $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
   // Save file status.
   file_save($file);
   global $user; 
   $na = 0;
   $istat = 1;
   db_insert('job_mp_catalog')
     ->fields(array(
       'user_id' => $user->uid,
       'title' => $form_state['values']['title'],
       'descr' => $form_state['values']['descr'],
       'location' => $form_state['values']['location'],
       'image' => $file->fid,))
     ->execute();     
   drupal_set_message("successfully saved ");
   //Example:
   //drupal_goto("user/".$user->uid."/edit");
   drupal_goto("content/test-page");
   //drupal_set_message("successfully saved Job!");
 }
```

Comment: you can probably use `dpm()` on `$form_state` above `$file = $form_state['storage']['image'];` to check if storage index exist or not. And then use checks to avoid exceptions. Also there were extra curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to validate on submit function as follow

```
function my_module_image_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Upload file to upload_directory in the public files dir.
  $file = file_save_upload('image', array(
    'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
    'file_validate_image_resolution' => array('500x500', '100x100'),
  ), 'public://uploaded_images/', FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

  // Check if image upload was success.
  if ($file) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Image successfully uploaded.'), 'status');
  }
  else {
    form_set_error('image', t('Image was not uploaded.'));
  }
}
```

For more info please see [this](http://www.vaerenbergh.com/blog/upload-image-custom-module-form) article.

Comment: That certainly helped, Thanks! I am getting this error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in jobform_my_form_submit()"  at 'image' => $file->fid,)) when I do not upload an image.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the 'image' => $file->fid, part in the db_insert. I used visabhishek suggestion above but for the db_insert, I did the below with removing "'image' => $file->fid," in the else section.

Thanks for the help!

```
if ($file) {
   db_insert('job_mp_catalog')
     ->fields(array(
       'user_id' => $user->uid,
       'title' => $form_state['values']['title'],
       'descr' => $form_state['values']['descr'],
       'location' => $form_state['values']['location'],
       'image' => $file->fid,))
     ->execute();  

}
  else {  
      db_insert('job_mp_catalog')
        ->fields(array(
       'user_id' => $user->uid,
       'title' => $form_state['values']['title'],
       'descr' => $form_state['values']['descr'],
       'location' => $form_state['values']['location'],
     ->execute();
}
```